# What is the difference between a postman request and a request from heroku or localhost

Tags: api, heroku, request, cors, postman

I can make a request from postman but when I make the same exact request (I'm talking about even copying the code from postman) I get an error.

> Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://glacial-stream-35306.herokuapp.com' is therefore not allowed access.

Even with the cors-eveywhere chrome extension and attempting to use jsonp I cannot get it to work. Even though the request goes through every time on postman.

What makes a postman req different from a request from a Heroku app?